# How to fix redirect chain issue using htacces

Tags: http-redirect

there is a redirect chain issue on my website, regarding ahref testing tool: http://www.website.com/ ; http://website.com/ ; https://www.website.com/.

https://website.com/ - I use this link.

This code is written in the htaccess file, which probably cause the problem:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
Header set Strict-Transport-Security: "max-age=31442830; includeSubDomains; preload"
```

Answer (score 0):

The htaccess logic above should not cause a redirect unless you have a Cloudflare  integration or Proxy that does not pass the secure protocol along to the apache server

if you have WordPress then a redirect can be made internally

Comment: thanks, I will check it in WP

Comment: No worries, if it worked then please mark the answer as verified